# Jackson exception handling - How to get all unmapped fields

Tags: java, spring, jackson

The question is about correct handling of type miss matching in the json input.

So, I have simple class

```java
class Entity {
  Integer fst;
  Integer snd;
}
```

And this json

```json
{
  "fst": "not_correct_fst",
  "snd": "not_correct_snd"
}
```

And I want to produce similar errors in the my ControllerAdvice

```
{
  "type_errors": {
     "fst": "not_correct_fst",
     "snd": "not_correct_snd"
   }
}
```

But in the HttpMessageNotReadable handler I can get only first error (it's about `fst` field), cuz jackson stop parsing after first error happened.

**Is there any option to collect all field errors?**

I tried to use `DeserializationProblemHandler`, I can put all errors to the `DeserializationContext` object, but I don't found any way to throw an exception with all these errors at the end of parsing.

Comment: If `fst` and `snd` are strings, why would you map them to `Integer`'s? Once you know they're strings, in `Entity` class they should be declared as Strings.

Comment: I need `fst` and `snd` to be integers. String type in input json is a wrong user input, comes from network. I want to implement correct exception handling in a case when user enter incorrect type.

Comment: If exception handling is what is needed than I guess it is fine to interrupt processing and handle just the first wrong value which caused the error. If you can control the user input you could also add client side validations.

Answer (score 0):

You should rely on validation to respond to such case.

First, add the dependency (I assume you use spring boot)

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```

Then, annotate the validation rules on the Entity:

```
class Entity {
  @NotNull
  @Min(1)
  @Max(20)
  Integer fst;
  Integer snd;
}
```

Finally, in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/entities", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Entity> saveEntity(
        @Valid @RequestBody Entity entity) {
    return new ResponseEntity<Entity>(entity, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

There are several resources speaking about this topic, the first I found is:

https://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/017-validate-spring-rest-webservice-request/